# Glassware for Beer

Tags: taste, glassware

It's kind of simple question, I'd like to know why exists different kinds of glass for each beer. Could glass affect beer taste? How? Or is this just marketing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people would say yes, it does make a difference. Take a read of this article for some thoughts:

http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/innovations/wp/2014/07/11/can-this-glass-actually-make-beer-taste-better/

The type of glass can effect not only the aromas imparted to your nose but also how quickly the beer warms up and also the visual appeal too. I tell people you first taste things with your eyes, then your nose, then your mouth.